How does JSI ensures synchronicity?
In the new architecture of react native(Fabric), I get that JSON serialization/de-serialization is not required from the JS -> Native side, as that is replaced by JSI layer(C++ host objects) but how is the communication from Native -> JS happening now? Is native side also holding some sort of reference?
The broader question here is, until and unless native -> JS call is not happening via some reference rather JSON, how is it synchronous?
As per my understanding, the call should be looking like this in new architecture on a very high level:
OnClickEvent()
{
   doSomeLogic()
   
   newView = _cppRefForJS()
   
   newView.render()    
}

Can someone please point out what's going on in Native -> JS side or what am I getting wrong here? I was unable to find any resources on this, most of the videos/blogs are only on JS -> Native communication.
